# MySQL I/O bound InnoDB query optimization problem without setting innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5GB

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I got myself into a MySQL design scalability issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**The requirements:**

Storing users' SOCIAL_GRAPH and USER_INFO about each user in their social graph. Many concurrent reads and writes per second occur. Dirty reads acceptable.

**Current design:**

We have 2 (relevant) tables. Both InnoDB for row locking, instead of table locking.

1. USER_SOCIAL_GRAPH table that maps a logged in (user_id) to another (related_user_id). PRIMARY key composite user_id and related_user_id.
2. USER_INFO table with information about each related user. PRIMARY key is (related_user_id).

Note 1: No relationships defined.

Note 2: Each table is now about 1GB in size, with 8 million and 2 million records, respectively.

**Simplified table SQL creates:**

```
CREATE TABLE `user_social_graph` (
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `related_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`related_user_id`),
  KEY `user_idx` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `user_info` (
  `related_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET latin1 DEFAULT NULL,
  [... and many other non-indexed fields irrelevant]
  `last_updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`related_user_id`),
  KEY `last_updated_idx` (`last_updated`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**MY.CFG values set:**

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
key_buffer_size         = 320M
```

Note 3: Memory available 1GB, these 2 tables are 2GBs, other innoDB tables 3GB.

**Problem:**

The following example SQL statement, which needs to access all records found, takes 15 seconds to execute (!!) and num_results = 220,000:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE COUNT(u.related_user_id) 
FROM user_info u LEFT JOIN user_socialgraph u2 ON u.related_user_id = u2.related_user_id 
WHERE u2.user_id = '1' 
AND u.related_user_id = u2.related_user_id 
AND (NOT (u.related_user_id IS NULL));
```

For a user_id with a count of 30,000, it takes about 3 seconds (!).

EXPLAIN EXTENDED for the 220,000 count user. It uses indices:

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys          | key      | key_len | ref                | rows   | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u2    | ref    | user_user_idx,user_idx | user_idx | 4       | const              | 157320 |   100.00 | Using where              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | u     | eq_ref | PRIMARY                | PRIMARY  | 4       | u2.related_user_id |      1 |   100.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+------------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+--------+----------+--------------------------+
```

How do we speed these up without setting innodb_buffer_pool_size to 5GB?

Thank you!

Comment: Note: The 'user_user_idx' shown in EXPLAIN is the same as PRIMARY of the user_social_graph table.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it seems there is not correct answer. What I did to make the execution time acceptable is set the following my.cfg values: innodb_buffer_pool_size = 612M, innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT (to skip double caching), and innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1 (see http://bit.ly/fMXtzA). Not very scalable, but acceptable.

Comment: Can you clarify what you're hoping to accomplish with this query? For example, if you're just looking to count the number of related user IDs for the user with ID 1, it's as simple as: **SELECT count(*) FROM user_social_graph WHERE user_id = 1**.

Comment: Also, your JOIN and WHERE condition are redundant.

Comment: Also, the **(NOT (u.related_user_id IS NULL))** WHERE condition is redundant, since **related_user_id** is defined as **NOT NULL**.

Answer (score 1):

The user_social_graph table is not indexed correctly !!!

You have ths:

CREATE TABLE `user_social_graph`
(`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`related_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`related_user_id`),
KEY `user_idx` (`user_id`))
ENGINE=InnoDB;

The second index is redundant since the first column is user_id. You are attempting to join the related_user_id column over to the user_info table. That column needed to be indexed.

Change user_social_graphs as follows:

CREATE TABLE `user_social_graph`
(`user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`related_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`related_user_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `related_user_idx` (`related_user_id`,`user_id`))
ENGINE=InnoDB;

This should change the EXPLAIN PLAN. Keep in mind that the index order matters depending the the way you query the columns.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: You are right. That index was not the best choice. I did the changes you suggested, and they did not help. The EXPLAIN plan looks better, but it's still I/O bound and slow (same as before). I had to use FORCE KEY FOR JOIN(related_user_idx) to get MySQL to use the new index, and is now shown on the EXPLAIN. Any ideas? Why isn't MySQL using the indices for COUNT()?

Comment: I would at least double the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 512M. Also, I would set innodb_log_file_size to 128M. After setting those values in /etc/my.cnf, make sure you do the following: 1) shutdown mysql, 2) rm /var/lib/mysql/ib_logfile*, 3) restart mysql.

Comment: COUNT() against InnoDB NEVER USES INDEXES. When you do "SHOW INDEXES FROM tblname" when the table is InnoDB, you get a different number for cardinality each time. That happens because the InnoDB Storage Engine does indexes dives into the index to guess the cardinality for the sake of the MySQL Query Optimizer. Thus, the index is considered totally unreliable for getting a table count BY DESIGN. MySQL will thus initiate a full table scan against an InnoDB table every time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's indeed 2x faster with innodb_buffer_pool_size set to 512M. But I am sure we're missing something. As you can see from the original EXPLAIN output, it's using indices, so why does it read the records from disk to count them?

Comment: The page just updated with your newer comment. You are right about COUNT and indices. I have an idea that I am not 100% sure how to execute. If I convert those tables to MyISAM, is there a way to work around the table-locking so that INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE statements could run almost simultaneously? I am guessing QUICK, and DELAYED keywords would help.

Comment: You cannot "work around" table-level locking. The problem is not the storage engine, and it's certainly not the server settings--the problem is your query and your indexing.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is the MySQL version? Its manual contains important information for speeding up statements and code in general;
2. Change your paradigm to a data warehouse capable to manage till terabyte table. Migrate your legacy MySQL data base with free tool or application to the new paradigm. This is an example: http://www.infobright.org/Downloads/What-is-ICE/ many others (free and commercial).
3. PostgreSQL is not commercial and there a lot of tools to migrate MySQL to it!

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I'm not really looking to move to a different database system at the moment, as I am sure MySQL could be tweaked to handle the few scenarios we have. Could you please elaborate more on point #2. A link maybe? Plus, why do you think PostgreSQL would solve the concurrency problem?